# Map JSONObject to SQL server

Tags: java, json, sql-server-2012-express

I know the title is quite cliched, but it is not about storing JSON data in SQL Server.

I have a `JSONArray` with JSONObjects with keys that match the column names in SQL Server 2012. I want to save the data to the database into the proper columns.

I know the obvious way to do this is the iterate through the `JSONArray` and save the values with individual insert commands. I was wondering if there was another way to do this.

I don't want to use T-SQL. I want to handle this from Java only.

Here is an example data that matches the format of my `JSONArray`:

```
[
    {
        "FEATURE":"A",
        "OPTION":"92384",
        "ERROR_TYPE":"MISSING",
        "DESCRIPTION":"Feature A is missing the option 92384",
        "SERIAL_NUMBER":"249752-23894"
    },
    {
        "FEATURE":"B",
        "OPTION":"0288394",
        "ERROR_TYPE":"MISSING",
        "DESCRIPTION":"Feature B is missing the option 0288394",
        "SERIAL_NUMBER":"Y2394-20392Q"
    }
]
```

My SQLServer table looks like this:
[image: SQL table]

What would be best way to achieve this without looping through each `JSONArray`?

Comment: I would suggest you use nvarchar instead of varchar. You might run into encoding difficulties along the way otherwise.

Comment: @Tschallacka Noted. Will change that.

Comment: If you can update your database software to 2016 you can use nifty features such as https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/json/use-for-json-output-in-sql-server-and-in-client-apps-sql-server

Comment: @Tschallacka I am aware that SQLServer 2016 supports a lot of features regarding JSON, but my project has been set entirely on SQLServer 2012 - so, changing it is a no go.

Answer (score 1):

As you have added java tag I would convert JSON to Java object and save it with Hibernate. Here are two useful links how to do that
[Json to Java](https://www.mkyong.com/java/jackson-2-convert-java-object-to-from-json/) 
[Hibernate example](http://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/maven-hibernate-annonation-mysql-example/)

Comment: JSON data is being generated based on another functionality. I went for JSON rather than Java object intentionally - because it suits by business requirement. Also, I don't know how else to put this, but I cannot use Hibernate/Maven where I'm working. It has to be purely Java only.

Answer (score -1):

```
DECLARE @testJson NVARCHAR(4000)= N'[{"id":2,"name":"n2"},{"id":1,"name":"n1"}]'

INSERT
INTO
    test_table SELECT
        *
    FROM
        OPENJSON(@testJson) WITH (
            id int N'$.id',
            name VARCHAR(200) N'$.name'
        )
```

**Update**

use java

jsonStr -> jsonObject  and getKeys   (some json libs )

```
String youJson = "{\"id\":0, \"name\":\"n0\"}";
JsonParser parser = new JsonParser();
JsonObject jsonObject = parser.parse(json).getAsJsonObject();
Set<String> keys = jsonObject.keySet();
```

Then use NamedParameterJdbcTemplate and MapSqlParameterSource   (spring-jdbc) to  create sql and set parameters dynamically .

PS. I hate ORM in java.

Comment: Op stated sql server 2012. Not 2016

Comment: why not use T-SQL?

Comment: A) op stated no t-sql, B) the feature from your answer is only available from sql server 2016. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/openjson-transact-sql @op is using sql server 2012

Comment: Please read the entire question. I have a the json data in a JSONArray of JSONObjects already. I was wondering if there's an alternate way of mapping them to the db directly without iterating through the entire dataset.

Comment: JdbcTemplate().batchUpdate()